# How to understand "Immediately Expanded Variable Assignment" in GNU make documentation?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My English is poor. I read the GNU `make` documentation, and I understand variable assignment using `=`, `:=`, or `::=`. But I don't understand "Immediately Expanded Variable Assignment" with `:::=`.

Would someone explain, please?

Comment: John's answer is _excellent_.  Another tip is if you want to understand how things behave you can use GNU Make's `$(value ...)` function to see the content of a variable without any further expansion.  This can help you see the difference (for example show it with the `$(info ...)` function).

Answer (score 2):

GNU `make` has two flavors of variables:

- ***recursively expanded*** variables. Whenever such a variable is expanded, the expansion is rescanned for variable and function references, and these are expanded recursively according to their flavors.
- ***simply expanded*** variables. When such a variable is expanded, the text is used exactly as-is, without further expansion.

GNU `make` has *three* kinds of variable assignment:

- ***Recursively expanded variable assignment*** is expressed with the operator `=` and creates a recursively expanded variable.  The assigned text is stored literally in the variable, without any expansion.

  ```
  recursively_expanded = $(not) $(expanded) $(yet)
  ```
- ***Simply expanded variable assignment*** is expressed with the operator `:=` or `::=` and creates a simply expanded variable.  The assigned text is fully expanded at the time of the assignment.

  ```
  simply_expanded := $(expanded) $(right) $(now)
  ```
- ***Immediately expanded variable assignment*** is expressed with the operator `:::=`.  Like recursively expanded variable assignment, it creates a **recursively expanded** variable.  Similar to simply expanded variable assignment, the assigned text is fully expanded at assignment time (that is, immediately), but then it is escaped to protect against further expansion when the variable is (recursively) expanded.

  ```
  recursively_expanded_2 :::= $(expanded) $(right) $(now)
  ```

You can imagine immediately expanded variable assignment as a way to get most of the behavior and efficiency of a simply expanded variable while using a recursively expanded variable.  That was presumably the idea behind this feature in BSD `make`, where it is expressed via `:=` instead of via GNU's `:::=`.

For almost all purposes, simply expanded variables are a better choice than recursively expanded variables initialized via immediately expanded variable assignment.  However, there may occasionally be a situation where you want part of a variable's text to be expanded when assigned, but other parts to be expanded when the variable is expanded.  In such a case, you can use immediate assignment to get assignment-time expansion, and then *append* the text you want recursively expanded:

```
recursively_expanded_2   += $(not) $(expanded) $(yet)
```